# Multiple if(strlen) with different value?

Tags: php

So I am trying to have two if(strlen) but the top one is the only one that displays even if it's the call sign error? Updated to have the full list of code.

```
    final public function register()
    {
            global $core, $template, $_CONFIG;
            
            if(isset($_POST['register']))
            {
                    unset($template->form->error);
                    
                    $template->form->setData();
                    $name = $template->form->reg_name;
                    if($this->validName($name))
                    {
                        if(!$this->nameTaken($name))
                        {
                            if(!$this->emailTaken($template->form->reg_email))
                            {
                                if(strlen($template->form->reg_password) >= 8)
                                {
                                    if(strlen($template->form->reg_callsign) > 2)
                                    {
                                        if(!$this->callTaken($template->form->reg_callsign))
                                        {
                                            if($this->isBanned($_SEVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) == false)
                                            {
                                                if($template->form->reg_email == $template->form->reg_rep_email)
                                                {
                                                    if($this->validEmail($template->form->reg_email))
                                                    {
                                                        $this->addUser($name, $core->hashed($template->form->reg_password), $template->form->reg_email, $template->form->reg_callsign, 1, $core->hashed);
                                                        $this->turnOn($name);
                                                        
                                                        header('Location: ' . $_CONFIG['game']['url'] . '/application');
                                                        exit;
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        $template->form->error = 'Oops, email seems to be invalid.';
                                                        return;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    $template->form->error = 'Email & repeated email doesn\'t match.';
                                                    return;
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                $template->form->error = 'Sorry, it appears you are banned.<br />';
                                                $template->form->error .= 'Reason: ' . $this->getReason($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
                                                return;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            $template->form->error = 'That call sign is already taken!';
                                            return;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $template->form->error = 'Your call sign must be 3 digits.';
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $template->form->error = 'Make sure your password has 8 characters or more.';
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $template->form->error = 'Oops, this email is already registered.';
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $template->form->error = 'Oops, this name:<b>' . $name . '</b> is taken.';
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $template->form->error = 'Oops, this name is invalid.';
                        return;
                    }
            }
    }
```

What I would like to happen is where if(strlen($template->form->reg_password) >= 8) (error message) would only show up if the password is shorter than 8 and the if(strlen($template->form->reg_callsign) > 2) (error message) to show up if they are only putting 1-2 numbers and not 3

Comment: May I recommend using the ["return early pattern"](https://medium.com/swlh/return-early-pattern-3d18a41bba8) where all checks and failing are put in the beginning of the function, like [here](https://gist.github.com/md2perpe/a777fa0b7ae217c0d97efb7ea0a07eba/c336804d91baf2365c4be674d6724cf2ac7caaef)? You can even merge the tests like I have done [here](https://gist.github.com/md2perpe/a777fa0b7ae217c0d97efb7ea0a07eba/23a3341732039cd259920f10b9e2ecc248dd1e46). Note: the code hasn't been tested.

Comment: I will give your code a try once I get home.

Comment: @md2perpe So I am running into this error now when trying run the first one, the one you made works like mine where it will only show the make sure your password is 8 characters + even though I am leaving out the call sign on purpose. The error I am getting with the first one: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in htdocs\app\class.members.php on line 116 Which is this code: foreach ($checks as [$condition, $error_message])

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: Ah found out why I haven't updated it from 5.4.31

Comment: I haven't really used PHP for some years, but PHP 5 is quite old now.

Comment: Yeah I didn't realize I was still rocking PHP 5 probably why I have ran into many errors lately.

Comment: @md2perpe Sorry to bug you again, I have been racking my brain trying to recode everything into PHP 8 so I tried PHP 7, and still a headache. Do you know if there is a way that I could use two strlen the way I have it at all?

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem and what you want in your question. Do you want to show a list of everything that is wrong?

Comment: I know there is a lot wrong, I am starting kind of fresh and trying to learn PDO. I am so used to how I coded back in 2011 that it is a learning curve again.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that there is a lot wrong. I meant: What do you want to do? Do you want to show a list of all errors?

Comment: Oh, copy that. So I am trying to make it show if you have an error it would come back with what the error is. So for example, if you have less than 8 characters in your pass it would come back "Make sure your password is 8+ characters" and same with the if you left the call sign blank or less than 3 it would come back as "Please make sure your call sign is 3 digits" but all that is coming back for the call sign one is the password error

Comment: Do you get the password error even if the password is long enough?

Comment: Yes, even if I have the password above 8 characters it still shows the password error for the call sign.

Comment: Did I understand that correctly? If the password is long enough, the call sign check should not run? Should there be *either* a password *or* a call sign?

Comment: No, I want it to check for everything in that code so if the call sign is not 3 digits I want it to throw an error. The problem I am having is the password length_error is the error that is thrown for the password if it's not long enough which is correct and it throws an error if the call sign is below 3 which is incorrect.

Comment: I'm still confused. Could you give a concrete example?